# Beginner Java programmer arithmetic error

Tags: java, programming-languages, math

I've recently embarked into Java programming and consider myself a programing novice. It seem that I'm having an issue with my source code arithmetic. I have verified all the nested if-else statements and they all work up to the final else statement's arithmetic. It doesn't calculating correctly I have set the arithmetic up just as the above if-else statements.

the else statement is suppose to subtract 40 from the amount and then apply 1 percent charge.

This is just an exercise from the book

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ServiceCharge {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double checkAmount;
    double fee;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("I will calulate the service charge to cash your check");
    System.out.print("Enter amount of check: $");
    checkAmount = kb.nextDouble();

    if (checkAmount > 0)
    {
        if (checkAmount <= 10)
        {
            fee = -1;
            System.out.println("$1 service charge");
            checkAmount = checkAmount + fee;
            System.err.println("You have " + checkAmount + " left after service charge.");
        }
        else if ((checkAmount > 10) && (checkAmount <= 100))
        {
            System.out.println("There will be a 10 percent charge.");
            fee = (checkAmount * .10);
            checkAmount = checkAmount - fee;
            System.out.printf("Processing fee: $%.2f\n" , fee);
            System.out.printf("Check amount: $%.2f\n" , checkAmount);
        }
        else if ((checkAmount > 100) && (checkAmount <= 1000))
        {
            System.out.println("There will be a $5 charge plus 5 percent");
            fee = ((checkAmount - 5) * .05);
            checkAmount = (checkAmount - fee);
            System.out.printf("Processing fee: $%.2f\n" , fee);
            System.out.printf("Check amount: $%.2f\n", checkAmount);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("$40 processing fee plus 1 percent");
            fee = ((checkAmount - 40) * .01);
            checkAmount = (checkAmount - fee);
            System.out.printf("Processing fee: $%.2f\n" , fee);
            System.out.printf("Check amount: $%.2f\n" , checkAmount);
        }
        System.out.println("Thanks for using Service Charger." + "\nGood bye");
    }
}
}
```

Revised code